# xiaomi rejected mono shared runtime installation request (xamarin.android)

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I have developed a mobile application for a certain business. We are now trying to test it through different mobile. But suddenly, the problem is in the mobile itself. I don't know why the Xiaomi Note 3 declines installation request.

I already enabled the developers option and the usb debugging. I am missing something in here?
I already disabled and enabled the fast deployment.

**EDIT**

I forgot to include that I already tried to disable the use shared runtime

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> additional settings -> Developer Options -> Debugging options -> Check Install via USB and check USB debugging

You are good to go :)

Comment: there is no debugging option under developer options but there is an "Install via USB" which is already enabled .

Comment: also enable USB debugging.

Comment: yes it is enabled sir. The problem is with xiaomi and mono runtime. not the debugging process.